# How to write a unit test for method that yields an object to the block in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have a class that implements a `.call` method that yields an object to the block and I would like to learn how to write a unit test for this. Here's what I have.

```
module A
  class B < Service
    def call(object_id:)
      @object = Something.find(object_id)
      @object.update(status: 'done')
      yield @object
    end

    def set_to_in_progress
      @object.update(status: 'in_progress')
    end
  end
end

class Service
  def self.call(*args); new.call(*args); end
end
```

Then I use it like this:

```
A::B.call(obj) do |object|
  object.set_to_in_progress if some_other_condition?
end
```

I need to be able to write a unit test for `call` method that tests whether the status has changed to done or in progress. Here's what I have:

```
RSpec.describe A::B, :unit do
  let(:object) { create(:something, id: 1, status: 'in_progress') }

  it 'updates the status to done' do
    described_class.call(object.id) do |???|
      ???
    end

    expect(object.status).to equal('done')
  end

  it 'updates the status to in progress' do
    described_class.call(object.id) do |???|
      ???
    end

    expect(object.status).to equal('in_progress')
  end
end
```

Comment: Will this spec not fail because `Something.find(object_id)` will not find a record since you never create one in the spec?

Comment: @Kris You're right, good spot! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`yield_with_args` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/built-in-matchers/yield-matchers#yield-with-args-matcher):

```rb
specify do
  expect { |block| described_class.call(object.id, &block) }
    .to yield_with_args(object)
end
```

Just a side note that you're mixing testing of behaviour (yields `object`) and side effects (`object` has been changed).

Answer (score 0):

You could return the object in `#call`:

```
def call(object_id:)
  @object = Something.find(object_id)
  @object.update(status: 'done')
  yield @object
  @object
end
```

Then in the test you can do:

```
object = described_class.call(object.id)
expect(object.status).to eq('in_progress')
```